# How to get a group or OU's active directory path in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, path, active-directory, ldap

I need to get the path from the domain controller to any group or OU that I have the DN for.

Comment: The DN is the path in AD, effectively. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I suppose I was just being lazy. I was trying to find out if there was a property or function that printed it like  DomainController/OU/OU/Group    nicely

Comment: I guess I could just rearrange the DN string to get that configuration

Comment: Though if there is a shortcut to get it that way it'd be good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask AD for the `canonicalName` attribute I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: How would I ask for that in VBScript

Comment: Though maybe that should be its own question